# Xcode "Building" a Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Honestly, I don't fully understand my question, but hopefully I can still be fairly clear about it.

I just wrote a simple project in Objective-C/Xcode. It looks like Xcode generated an executable in a folder called "Debug" and when I double-click on it, it opens a terminal window and runs fine. However, while running, it reads from a text file in the same directory that it's in. So if I want move the executable to a different location, I also have to move the text file to the same location or it won't be able to find the text file.

My question is... when I download an application on my computer (like Google Chrome or Evernote), it comes as its own file and I can place it in any directory I like; there are no associated files I have to move whenever I move the "executable". Is there a way to generate a clean application like this using Xcode?

Comment: How is the text file related to your application? It seems unrelated to your question. Also, consider reading https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

Comment: For a MacOS app, the full package containing binaries, resources, etc is called a bundle  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html